# How to call Behat step programmatically? Warning: Missing argument 2 for Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\Given::__construct()

Tags: php, behat

I have behat 3.0.15 and I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.gizra.com/content/behat-the-right-way/) when creating my first Behat tests.

Code:

```
/**
 * @When I go to see akaneo product page for :country written in :language language   
 */
public function findOrCreateProductForCountryAndVisitIt($country, $language)
{
    global $user;
    $node = new stdClass;
    $node->title = 'Test Product';
    $node->type = 'akaneo_product';
    node_object_prepare($node);
    $node->uid = $user->uid;
    $node->status = 1;
    $node->language = $language;
    #load domain id for country
    $result = db_select('domain', 'd')
        ->fields('d', array('domain_id'))
        ->condition('subdomain',  strtolower($country) . '_schiller.%', 'LIKE')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAssoc();



    if (empty($result)) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot find subsidiary for country code: $country");
    }

    $node->domains = array(
      $result['domain_id'] => $result['domain_id']
    );

    $node = $this->nodeCreate($node);

    return new Given('I go to node/' . $node->nid);

}
```

Output:

```
  Warning: Missing argument 2 for Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\Given::__construct(), called in features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php on line 435 and defined in vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Definition/Call/Given.php line 27
│
╳  Unable to access the response content before visiting a page (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)
│
└─ @AfterStep # ScreenshotContext::logResponseAfterFailedStep()
```

What should I pass as callable contructor parameter?

Comment: How does your step look like? Can you add the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaining steps is not possible in Behat 3.
If you want to reuse some code, just follow regular OOP approach - extract common code to a separate method or class.

You will find the explanation for removal here: https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/546#issuecomment-45202991

Comment: So there is no way to pass ID for created content in custom step to another one?

Comment: You can pass this ID as a parameter to another method.

Comment: I'd also like to discourage you from using global variables. If you want `$user` to be defined for all steps in Behat, use [scenario hooks](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/user_guide/context/hooks.html#scenario-hooks) (or those with bigger scope if necessary). Global variables in OOP are seldom a good idea.

Comment: Oh you can, but this is Drupal 7 thing, instead of this I can use 0 as user ID, no big deal. It's just my playground, not production code yet. But of course you are right